# how do I translate of lon/lat coordinate by some N-E meters distance on earth surface?

Tags: c++, math, geolocation, coordinates, geospatial

how do I get a new coordinate in geodetic (Lat/Lon) from a reference point (which is in geodetic) after some translation (in meters) on earth surface, and also I need to do the calculation using true earth ellipsoid model such as WGS84.

for example:

- suppose I have reference point of 10.32E, -4.31N
- then I do translation of (3000,-2000) meters ( which is move the point 3000 meters to east and 2000 meters to south **on earth surface**.
- then I need the coordinate of new point **in geodetic**.

thank you

Comment: When you talk about moving east and south, do you really mean moving along lines of latiude and longitude? Or do you mean moving along the grid lines of some other grid, such as the Ordnance Survey Grid used in Britain.

Comment: it is along lines of lat/lon. that's why I called it north/south - east/west but I need to move not in degree unit of spherical coordinate but in meters of cartesian of the earth surface and I need the result in spherical coordinate again (well not spherical, it should be ellipsoidal)

Comment: And in what order ? East then south, or south then east ? There is a difference.

Comment: on east/west first then north/south, note: the "meter" distance is not distance on straight line it is "arc-length" since it is a distance on spherical surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer :

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty-direct.html

from: 
Vincenty direct formula - T Vincenty, "Direct and Inverse Solutions of Geodesics on the
Ellipsoid with application of nested equations", Survey Review, vol XXII no 176, 1975

http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the open-source library [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) which you can use to accurately translate geographic coordinates (lat/long) to projected coordinates (metres), and back again. In your case you can project into WGS 84 / World Mercator ([EPSG:3395](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/)), perform the translation in metres, then un-project back to geographic.

Comment: currently I'am doing like that, which is transform current reference point of geodetic (lat/lon) into UTM (universal tranverse mercator) and do movement using UTM coordinate,then convert back new position from UTM into geodetic, but there is one thing I hate about UTM is they have zone/sphere enumeration, I'am looking for mercator projection without any zoning, do you know some?

Comment: The WGS84 World Mercator is not the same as UTM. The projected bounds of the WGS84 World Mercator are: -20037508.3428, -15496570.7397, 20037508.3428, 18764656.2314. This covers the whole world.

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates the distance (N and E) between two points given lat/lon coordinates. You can easily reverse it for your purposes.

Take a look at function

```
u8 GPS_CalculateDeviation()
```

in

http://svn.mikrokopter.de/filedetails.php?repname=NaviCtrl&path=/tags/V0.15c/GPS.c

Comment: if it is about getting distance between two lat/lon coord, there is better article and code : http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html , but reversing it is not an easy task, that's why i'am asking here

Comment: @uray: Even (possibly expensive) numerical inversion won't do ?

Comment: @alex: well I'am not expert at geodesic math since it involve ellipsoid surface, if it is perfect spherical maybe it would be simpler

Comment: @uray: It does not depend on the underlying model, you have a function which takes a position and gives you back a displacement. You invert it with eg. Newton's method with finite difference derivatives.

Comment: Using this is simple. Just get the arc length for 1 degree north of where you are, divide your translation north by that to get change in latitude. Then get the arc length for one degree east from your new position, and divide your east translation by that number to get your change in longitude.

Comment: @null: I can't do that, I need accuracy to centimeters

Answer (score 0):

You either find some geo-library, or do the trigonometry yourself.

In any case you should formulate your question more exactly. In particular you say:

> then I do translation of (3000,-2000) meters ( which is move the point 3000 meters to east and 2000 meters to south on earth surface.

You should note that moving by 3km to east and then 2km to south **differs** from moving 2km to south and then 3km to east. Those are not commutative actions. So that calling this by offsetting (3000, -2000) is incorrect.

Comment: "or do the trigonometry yourself" not a trivial task: the surface of the earth is not a sphere.

Comment: Nope, as Raedwald indicated it's not math. There's insufficient information. The question already acknowledged that when it pointed out the need for the WGS-84 model.

Comment: @Raedwald: I didn't say it's a trivial task. However it's still lies in the field of the analytical geometry. With the appropriate math background there's no problem to do this

Answer (score 0):

Below is C++ code slighly modified from [original version from ETH Zurich](https://github.com/ethz-asl/geodetic_utils/blob/master/include/geodetic_utils/geodetic_conv.hpp). The file only has dependency on [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) (which can be eliminated with some trivial work if required by writing matrix multiplication function yourself). You can use geodetic2ned() function to convert latitude, longitude, altitude to NED frame.

```
//GeodeticConverter.hpp
#ifndef air_GeodeticConverter_hpp
#define air_GeodeticConverter_hpp

#include <math>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

class GeodeticConverter
{
 public:
  GeodeticConverter(double home_latitude = 0, double home_longitude = 0, double home_altitude = 0)
    : home_latitude_(home_latitude), home_longitude_(home_longitude)
  {
    // Save NED origin
    home_latitude_rad_ = deg2Rad(latitude);
    home_longitude_rad_ = deg2Rad(longitude);
    home_altitude_ = altitude;

    // Compute ECEF of NED origin
    geodetic2Ecef(latitude, longitude, altitude, &home_ecef_x_, &home_ecef_y_, &home_ecef_z_);

    // Compute ECEF to NED and NED to ECEF matrices
    double phiP = atan2(home_ecef_z_, sqrt(pow(home_ecef_x_, 2) + pow(home_ecef_y_, 2)));

    ecef_to_ned_matrix_ = nRe(phiP, home_longitude_rad_);
    ned_to_ecef_matrix_ = nRe(home_latitude_rad_, home_longitude_rad_).transpose();    
  }

  void getHome(double* latitude, double* longitude, double* altitude)
  {
    *latitude = home_latitude_;
    *longitude = home_longitude_;
    *altitude = home_altitude_;
  }

  void geodetic2Ecef(const double latitude, const double longitude, const double altitude, double* x,
                     double* y, double* z)
  {
    // Convert geodetic coordinates to ECEF.
    // http://code.google.com/p/pysatel/source/browse/trunk/coord.py?r=22
    double lat_rad = deg2Rad(latitude);
    double lon_rad = deg2Rad(longitude);
    double xi = sqrt(1 - kFirstEccentricitySquared * sin(lat_rad) * sin(lat_rad));
    *x = (kSemimajorAxis / xi + altitude) * cos(lat_rad) * cos(lon_rad);
    *y = (kSemimajorAxis / xi + altitude) * cos(lat_rad) * sin(lon_rad);
    *z = (kSemimajorAxis / xi * (1 - kFirstEccentricitySquared) + altitude) * sin(lat_rad);
  }

  void ecef2Geodetic(const double x, const double y, const double z, double* latitude,
                     double* longitude, double* altitude)
  {
    // Convert ECEF coordinates to geodetic coordinates.
    // J. Zhu, "Conversion of Earth-centered Earth-fixed coordinates
    // to geodetic coordinates," IEEE Transactions on Aerospace and
    // Electronic Systems, vol. 30, pp. 957-961, 1994.

    double r = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    double Esq = kSemimajorAxis * kSemimajorAxis - kSemiminorAxis * kSemiminorAxis;
    double F = 54 * kSemiminorAxis * kSemiminorAxis * z * z;
    double G = r * r + (1 - kFirstEccentricitySquared) * z * z - kFirstEccentricitySquared * Esq;
    double C = (kFirstEccentricitySquared * kFirstEccentricitySquared * F * r * r) / pow(G, 3);
    double S = cbrt(1 + C + sqrt(C * C + 2 * C));
    double P = F / (3 * pow((S + 1 / S + 1), 2) * G * G);
    double Q = sqrt(1 + 2 * kFirstEccentricitySquared * kFirstEccentricitySquared * P);
    double r_0 = -(P * kFirstEccentricitySquared * r) / (1 + Q)
        + sqrt(
            0.5 * kSemimajorAxis * kSemimajorAxis * (1 + 1.0 / Q)
                - P * (1 - kFirstEccentricitySquared) * z * z / (Q * (1 + Q)) - 0.5 * P * r * r);
    double U = sqrt(pow((r - kFirstEccentricitySquared * r_0), 2) + z * z);
    double V = sqrt(
        pow((r - kFirstEccentricitySquared * r_0), 2) + (1 - kFirstEccentricitySquared) * z * z);
    double Z_0 = kSemiminorAxis * kSemiminorAxis * z / (kSemimajorAxis * V);
    *altitude = U * (1 - kSemiminorAxis * kSemiminorAxis / (kSemimajorAxis * V));
    *latitude = rad2Deg(atan((z + kSecondEccentricitySquared * Z_0) / r));
    *longitude = rad2Deg(atan2(y, x));
  }

  void ecef2Ned(const double x, const double y, const double z, double* north, double* east,
                double* down)
  {
    // Converts ECEF coordinate position into local-tangent-plane NED.
    // Coordinates relative to given ECEF coordinate frame.

    Vector3d vect, ret;
    vect(0) = x - home_ecef_x_;
    vect(1) = y - home_ecef_y_;
    vect(2) = z - home_ecef_z_;
    ret = ecef_to_ned_matrix_ * vect;
    *north = ret(0);
    *east = ret(1);
    *down = -ret(2);
  }

  void ned2Ecef(const double north, const double east, const double down, double* x, double* y,
                double* z)
  {
    // NED (north/east/down) to ECEF coordinates
    Vector3d ned, ret;
    ned(0) = north;
    ned(1) = east;
    ned(2) = -down;
    ret = ned_to_ecef_matrix_ * ned;
    *x = ret(0) + home_ecef_x_;
    *y = ret(1) + home_ecef_y_;
    *z = ret(2) + home_ecef_z_;
  }

  void geodetic2Ned(const double latitude, const double longitude, const double altitude,
                    double* north, double* east, double* down)
  {
    // Geodetic position to local NED frame
    double x, y, z;
    geodetic2Ecef(latitude, longitude, altitude, &x, &y, &z);
    ecef2Ned(x, y, z, north, east, down);
  }

  void ned2Geodetic(const double north, const double east, const double down, double* latitude,
                    double* longitude, double* altitude)
  {
    // Local NED position to geodetic coordinates
    double x, y, z;
    ned2Ecef(north, east, down, &x, &y, &z);
    ecef2Geodetic(x, y, z, latitude, longitude, altitude);
  }

  void geodetic2Enu(const double latitude, const double longitude, const double altitude,
                    double* east, double* north, double* up)
  {
    // Geodetic position to local ENU frame
    double x, y, z;
    geodetic2Ecef(latitude, longitude, altitude, &x, &y, &z);

    double aux_north, aux_east, aux_down;
    ecef2Ned(x, y, z, &aux_north, &aux_east, &aux_down);

    *east = aux_east;
    *north = aux_north;
    *up = -aux_down;
  }

  void enu2Geodetic(const double east, const double north, const double up, double* latitude,
                    double* longitude, double* altitude)
  {
    // Local ENU position to geodetic coordinates

    const double aux_north = north;
    const double aux_east = east;
    const double aux_down = -up;
    double x, y, z;
    ned2Ecef(aux_north, aux_east, aux_down, &x, &y, &z);
    ecef2Geodetic(x, y, z, latitude, longitude, altitude);
  }

private:
  // Geodetic system parameters
  static double kSemimajorAxis = 6378137;
  static double kSemiminorAxis = 6356752.3142;
  static double kFirstEccentricitySquared = 6.69437999014 * 0.001;
  static double kSecondEccentricitySquared = 6.73949674228 * 0.001;
  static double kFlattening = 1 / 298.257223563;

  typedef Eigen::Vector3d Vector3d;
  typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> Matrix3x3d;

  inline Matrix3x3d nRe(const double lat_radians, const double lon_radians)
  {
    const double sLat = sin(lat_radians);
    const double sLon = sin(lon_radians);
    const double cLat = cos(lat_radians);
    const double cLon = cos(lon_radians);

    Matrix3x3d ret;
    ret(0, 0) = -sLat * cLon;
    ret(0, 1) = -sLat * sLon;
    ret(0, 2) = cLat;
    ret(1, 0) = -sLon;
    ret(1, 1) = cLon;
    ret(1, 2) = 0.0;
    ret(2, 0) = cLat * cLon;
    ret(2, 1) = cLat * sLon;
    ret(2, 2) = sLat;

    return ret;
  }

  inline double rad2Deg(const double radians)
  {
    return (radians / M_PI) * 180.0;
  }

  inline double deg2Rad(const double degrees)
  {
    return (degrees / 180.0) * M_PI;
  }

  double home_latitude_rad_, home_latitude_;
  double home_longitude_rad_, home_longitude_;
  double home_altitude_;

  double home_ecef_x_;
  double home_ecef_y_;
  double home_ecef_z_;

  Matrix3x3d ecef_to_ned_matrix_;
  Matrix3x3d ned_to_ecef_matrix_;

}; // class GeodeticConverter

#endif
```